# PySpark Cum Sum of two values

Tags: python, pyspark

Given the following example dataframe:

```
advertiser_id| name | amount    | total             |max_total_advertiser|
4061         |source1|-434.955284|-354882.75336200005| -355938.53950700007
4061         |source2|-594.012216|-355476.76557800005| -355938.53950700007
4061         |source3|-461.773929|-355938.53950700007| -355938.53950700007
```

I need to sum the **amount** and the **max_total_advertiser** field in order to get the correct total value in each row. Taking into account that I need this **total** value for every group partitioned by advertiser_id. (The total column in the initial dataframe is incorrect, that's why I want to calculate correctly)

Something like that should be:

```
w = Window.partitionBy("advertiser_id").orderBy("advertiser_id")

df.withColumn("total_aux", when( lag("advertiser_id").over(w) == col("advertiser_id"), lag("total_aux").over(w) + col("amount") ).otherwise( col("max_total_advertiser") + col("amount") ))
```

This `lag("total_aux")` is not working because the column is not generated yet, that's what I want to achieve, if it is the first row in the group, sum the columns in the same row if not sum the previous obtained value with the current **amount** field.
Example output:

```
advertiser_id| name | amount    | total_aux             |
4061         |source1|-434.955284|-356373.494791    |
4061         |source2|-594.012216|-356967.507007    | 
4061         |source3|-461.773929|-357429.280936    |
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you rephrase the wall of text between the two code blocks? I read it trice and couldn't figure out what you want.

Comment: @leermeester I updated the text with a much simpler explanation, I think.

Comment: How do you define which of your records is the first one? By `name`? Is the value of `max_total_advertiser` always the same for a single `advertiser_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `name` is a distinct value for each `advertiser_id` and your dataset is therefore sortable by `name`. I also assume that `max_total_advertiser` contains the same value for each `advertiser_id`. If one of those is not the case, please add a comment.

What you need is a [rangeBetween](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window.rangeBetween) window which gives you all preceding and following rows within the specified range. We will use `Window.unboundedPreceding` as we want to sum up all the previous values.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

l = [
(4061, 'source1',-434.955284,-354882.75336200005, -355938.53950700007),
(4061, 'source2',-594.012216,-355476.76557800005, -345938.53950700007),
(4062, 'source1',-594.012216,-355476.76557800005, -5938.53950700007),
(4062, 'source2',-594.012216,-355476.76557800005, -5938.53950700007),
(4061, 'source3',-461.773929,-355938.53950700007, -355938.53950700007)
]

columns = ['advertiser_id','name' ,'amount', 'total', 'max_total_advertiser']

df=spark.createDataFrame(l, columns)

w = Window.partitionBy('advertiser_id').orderBy('name').rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

df = df.withColumn('total', F.sum('amount').over(w) + df.max_total_advertiser)
df.show()
```

Output:

```py
+-------------+-------+-----------+-------------------+--------------------+ 
|advertiser_id|   name|     amount|              total|max_total_advertiser| 
+-------------+-------+-----------+-------------------+--------------------+ 
|         4062|source1|-594.012216|-6532.5517230000705|   -5938.53950700007| 
|         4062|source2|-594.012216| -7126.563939000071|   -5938.53950700007| 
|         4061|source1|-434.955284| -356373.4947910001| -355938.53950700007| 
|         4061|source2|-594.012216| -346967.5070070001| -345938.53950700007| 
|         4061|source3|-461.773929|-357429.28093600005| -355938.53950700007| 
+-------------+-------+-----------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the `orderBy()` function. Does this work?

```
from pyspark.sql.window import *

df.withColumn("cumulativeSum", sum(df("amount"))
             .over( Window.partitionBy("advertiser_id").orderBy("amount")))
```

Comment: No, this does not work but because I didn't explain the problem correctly. I just updated again the explanation, I hope now is more clarifying.